# Orbit stability

Tags: orbital-mechanics

this is my first question, I am a space enthusiast but I don't have a formal understanding of celestial mechanics, so I would like to ask how stable against perturbation an orbit is, given the following assumptions:

- orbiting mass negligible vs massive center of orbit
- no atmosphere, no friction, no space dust in the way
- completely rigid bodies so no tidal concerns
- no solar radiation pressure, no Yarkovsky effect, etc
- no obscure funky disturbances not listed here
- object is in orbit at a given altitude with the proper speed for equilibrium

My perturbation would be a nudge either inwards or outward, e.g. turning on a propeller aimed at the orbit's center (or away from it) for a small amount of time.

What are the mechanics of this? Will the object settle in another stable orbit or will it slowly drift away / crash into the center?

My naive understanding is that, if I push inwards (thus not changing the *tangential* speed), the object would move to a closer potential orbit but its speed would be too low and it would spiral down to a crash, while it I push outwards the object would have a too fast *tangential speed* so it would drift away.

According to my (potentially flawed) reasoning, all orbits are unstable, meaning that you always tend to "diverge away" from that equilibrium, like a marble on top of a hill.

But how come satellite motions apparently tend to converge to a nice quasi-circular orbit and stay there (or even "get captured" while passing by)?

Could you please point me in the right direction?